# phpunit failing without any error

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpunit

I can't seem to figure this one out. I'm trying to get phpunit running on an ubuntu 12.04 server. It's for a codeigniter project so i'm using CIUNIT (https://bitbucket.org/kenjis/my-ciunit). I can get the example project and test working on the same box. I also have our tests setup locally and they work fine. For some reason, it doesn't want to work on our build server and it doesn't spit out any errors.

I think if it would just spit out some errors that would help immensely.

I've already checked the php.ini settings and i know that putting an error_log statement will produce output to stdout.

display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL

Answer (score 0):

Found while trying to deploy the actual php site that the server didn't have php setup with mysql so it was failing while trying to load the mysql driver.